# Check whether double holds integer, Math.rint vs %

Tags: java, math

I am trying to check whether a `double` **holds an integer value**, for example:

```
double d = 1.0; // true
double d = 1.2; // false
double d = 2.0; // yes
double d = 2.1; // false
```

I have two different approaches:

- `value % 1 == 0`
- `Math.rint(value) == value`

for example:

```
double x = 1.0;
double y = 1.2;
System.out.println(x % 1 == 0); //true
System.out.println(y % 1 == 0); //false
System.out.println(Math.rint(x) == x); //true
System.out.println(Math.rint(y) == y); //false
```

I am wondering about the differences between both approaches. Will they work for all integers? Is there a significant performance difference?

Are there better approaches to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: `math.rint(2.3) == 2.0` whereas `2.3 % 1 == 0.3`?

Comment: I think you're asking which way is better to determine if a double variable holds an integer value. But if so, you should say that in your question.

Comment: Right, I improved the objective of the question.

Comment: Both of your approaches are unusual and likely slower than the idiomatic ways like `x == (int) x` or similar. If you are really interested in performance differences, I suggest you measure it with a framework like JMH. However, the difference is likely so small that you should not care at all and just go for the most readable version (which neither of these are).

Comment: @Zabuzard Casting to int isn't helpful if `x` is outside the range of an int. `Math.rint` continues to work because it returns a double.

Comment: There's also `x == Math.floor(x)`

Comment: Just saying, you can also cast to `long`. In most cases this will likely do the trick. If not, sure, you can stick with `double` and try to round it.

Comment: It would be hard to measure the difference in performance between the options.

Comment: @Bohemian Why would it be hard?

Comment: If you're going to spend this much time on each line of your code, you're going to have a really fast program in 10 years.

Comment: @khelwood because the difference would likely be so small that other minute factors, such as what else was happening at the same time on the computer running it, eg other processes or GC etc, would have a significant effect on the timings. Which basically means "who cares" - all options are "very fast", so pick the one that's easiest to read

Comment: @Bohemian don't flood the comments. You don't want the *super*moderator to come after you.

Comment: In my program, of course, this is not the most important part. I'm just asking it for curiosity, I want to understand the math and the architecture used to handle these different approaches. That's a kind of questions that help us to expand our knowledge about the programming and math.

Comment: This is really a multipart question. 1. How do I check whether a double has no fraction. 2. Whether your modulo hack can be used for it. 3. If it can be used, is there a performance difference. For the last, which you seem to be most interested in, the answer is the least important, and it could (at least in theory) be opposite for Intel/AMD CPUs, making it impossible to choose the "faster" implementation. It's easy to fall into the micro-optimization trap before you understand where real performance comes from.